# Insert URL into BIRT Report that contains dynamic parameters

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am fairly new to BIRT and I am working on adding some new functionality to one of our existing reports.

We have an application that makes a call to BIRT to generate the report in question.  When this report is generated I would like to include a URL at the bottom of the report.

The only issue is that the URL would contain two parameters that are different for each report that gets generated.  I created a data source and a data set that I can pull the parameters from, but I am not sure how to create a URL with the parameters that relate to the particular report that is being generated.

I have read that you can create a label and insert a hyperlink, but this doesn't seem to be of much help in my situation.

The URL that gets inserted into the report would need to look as follows:

```
localhost:8080/Application?key=firstParameter&securityString=secondParameter
```

Please let me know if I did not explain my situation thoroughly or if you need more clarification.

Best Regards,

-Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

For example insert a new "Data" element to the report, set the datatype to "String" and enter as expression the text you want to display, i.e. "My URL" (with quotes because it is an expression).

Then click on "Binding" tab of this data element and select your dataset. Answer no to the question "Do you want to clear existing binding". In the popup, select all columns required to build the URL.

Finally use hyperlink property of the data element. May be you missed it can be an expression:

[image]

This pops up an expression builder, in your case this would result in something like:

```
"localhost:8080/Application?key="+row["firstParameter"]+"&securityString="+row["secondParameter"]
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need to accomplish my project.  The only issue I am running into is that when my report is generated, row["firstParameter"] and row["secondParameter"] are inserted into the URL as "null".  I ran the Data Set query in my SQL client just to be sure and it does return the values that I am looking for.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?  Please let me know if you need further information.  I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Nevermind it was an issue with my set up.  This was exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you very much for your help!